# question on combinatorics and number theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

We have an equation as:  $a\times b < n$ where $n$ is any positive integer.  Now my question is how many pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ can be found to satisfy the equation. For example, $a\times b < 3$ then the answer is $3$ as we have pairs $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$.

Comment: Given your solution to $n = 3$, it seems you require $a, b \in \mathbb N$, $a, b > 0$? Otherwise, there'd be infinitely many  solutions $(a, b)$, for integers $a, b$

Comment: @amWhy My edit is based on that observation.

Comment: Ah...missed the edit. Thanks, @drhab. I'll leave my question, just in case the OP wants to reply differently.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate, but [this recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743394) raises similar issues.

Comment: Is [*this*](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727630/number-of-ordered-pairs-a-b-such-that-ab-le-3600) a duplicate? Looking for opinion of others before voting.

Comment: Computing the first several terms of a sequence and checking with the OEIS is often a good idea.  In this case you get https://oeis.org/A006218

Comment: @Sabyasachi I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you define $d(k)$ as the number of divisors of $n$, the number of pair $(a,b)$ such that $ab=k$ is exactly $d(k)$, since for each divisor $a$ you have the pair $(a, k/a)$.

But what you are questioning about is the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}d(k)$$.

This is not a trivial matter, but there is a result obtained by Dirichlet in 1849:

$$\sum_{k\leq x} d(k)=x\log x+(2C-1)x+O(\sqrt x)$$

You can find a proof in *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* by Tom M. Apostol. I'd write it here, but it is pretty long.